# How to pass modal data into controller laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-7, laravel-8

I want to send modal data into controller using ajax . I am trying to send data but its not working below is my form

```
   <div class="modal-body">
        
    <form id="productForm" name="productForm" class="form-horizontal">
          {{ csrf_field() }}
          <div class="form-label-group">
          <label for="inputName">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="inputName" name="fname" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" value="{{old('fname')}}" autofocus>
          
          @if ($errors->has('fname'))
          <span class="error">{{ $errors->first('fname') }}</span>
          @endif       
          </div>
          <div class="form-label-group">
          <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" value="{{old('lname')}}" autofocus>
          
          @if ($errors->has('lname'))
          <span class="error">{{ $errors->first('lname') }}</span>
          @endif       
          </div> 
          <div class="form-label-group">
          <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
          <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" value="{{old('email')}}" placeholder="Email address" >
          
          @if ($errors->has('email'))
          <span class="error">{{ $errors->first('email') }}</span>
          @endif    
          </div> 

          <div class="form-label-group">
          <label for="inputusername">User Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="inputusername" name="username" class="form-control"  value="{{old('username')}}" placeholder="User name" autofocus>
          
          @if ($errors->has('username'))
          <span class="error">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</span>
          @endif       
          </div>

          <div class="form-label-group">
          <label for="inputusername">User Role</label>
          <select class="form-control" name="state" id="state-dropdown">
            <option value="">Select State</option>
           </select> 
          @if ($errors->has('username'))
          <span class="error">{{ $errors->first('username') }}</span>
          @endif       
          </div>

          
          <br>
          <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary edit_form" id="btn-save">Save changes
         </button>
          <!-- <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-cancel" value="create">Cancel
         </button> -->
       </div>

        </form>
        
        
    </div>
```

Below is my ajax jquery code from where data fetch nd append set into the input fields.

```
$('body').on('click', '.edit-user', function () {
        var user_id = $(this).attr('id');

        $.get('user-list/' + user_id +'/edit', function (data) {
                 console.log(data);
                var countryoption = "";
                $.each(data.roles, function(index, value) {

                    selectedVal = data.role;
                    isSelected = selectedVal == value.id ? 'selected' : '';

                    countryoption += "<option value='" + value.id + "' " + isSelected + ">" + value.role_name + "</option>";
                    });
                $('#state-dropdown').html(countryoption);
                 $('#title-error').hide();
                 $('#product_code-error').hide();
                 $('#description-error').hide();
                 $('#productCrudModal').html("Edit Product");
                  // $('#btn-save').val("edit-product");
                  $('#ajax-product-modal').modal('show');
                  $('#inputName').val(data.fname);
                  $('#lname').val(data.lname);
                  $('#inputEmail').val(data.email);
                  $('#inputusername').val(data.username);
                  
          });
    });
```

But when update data of form that time data not going into the controller. below is my ajax to send data of modal form to controller

```
$(document).on('click', '.edit_form', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
     var data = $('#productForm').serialize();
    //  alert(data);
     console.log(data);
                    $.ajax({
                              data: $('#productForm').serialize(),
                              url:"user-list/store",
                              type: "POST",
                              dataType: 'json',
                              success: function (data) {
                                console.log("hii");
                              },
                              error: function (data) {

                              }
                    })
    
    });
```

In console.log i am getting below data.

```
_token=3W55JanYYArPWGZbpigri3EvGpQvMKsyf4vLWgHa&fname=Praful&lname=R&email=praful.rambade06%40gmail.com&username=praful16&state=2&id=15
```

But i am trying to get data into controller for edit but not getting data into controller,

Below is my controller

```
public function userStore(Request $request)
    {
        echo "hii";
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($request);
        die;
    }
```

Nd below is my route for edit and when save data in edit

```
Route::get('/user-list/{id}/edit', 'UserController@editUser');
Route::post('user-list/store', 'UserController@userStore');
```

ANyone have idea then let me know what is the exact issue.